# Access VBA: issue on UPDATE statement (3144)

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access VBA, I have this code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Table Name] SET Note = 'aaaa' WHERE [Codice Progetto] = 'XX';"
```

But I get:

> Run-time error '3144': Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Doing some tests, I figured out the issue is related to the field ***Note***. I have checked that all the other part of the code are ok. I don't know why this issue because field Note exists and its characteristics are correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Note` is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2#__toc262648753) in MS Access.

Therefore, change your SQL to:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Table Name] SET [Note] = 'aaaa' WHERE [Codice Progetto] = 'XX';"
```